# ion-list display asynchronously added data to array

Tags: arrays, asynchronous, events, ionic-framework

I am new in ionic. I trying to make an app which will search for Bluetooth devices and will display them.
I have created a service which search for Bluetooth devices. When a device found an event publishes like below:

```
this.event.publish("ibeacon", newBeacon);
```

Here is my event injection:

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular/util/events';
......
constructor(private event: Events){}
```

Here is how I subscribe to the event in order to get the published data:

```
this.event.subscribe("ibeacon", (newBeacon) => {
  this.iBeacons.push(newBeacon);
});
```

As you can see I have declared an iBeacons Array where I push my received objects. The problem is when I try to display the iBeacons Array contents nothing displayed. Here is how I display my array:

```
<ion-content padding>

  <ion-list>
   <ion-item *ngFor="let beacon of iBeacons">
     <ion-label>
      {{ beacon.hash }}
     </ion-label>
   </ion-item>
 </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

The array at the beginning is empty.
I have have checked and I receive correctly my devices when I subscribe to the event.
I don't get errors.
I thing the data is not displayed because the data is added asynchronously in  iBeacons array. Any idea?

Here are some of the iBeacons Array contains:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {hash: "b5d787ac973341a59bf73838eededcb4", uuid: "fda50693-a4e2-4fb1-afcf-c6eb07647825", major: "10001", minor: "10301", lastFoundTime: 1518003454401}
1: {hash: "50aee081c9833e51ce00b9aa4a0c062d", uuid: "fda50693-a4e2-4fb1-afcf-c6eb07647825", major: "10001", minor: "10206", lastFoundTime: 1518003454391}
2: {hash: "1c8ecafb6efbbc37f905d95551291672", uuid: "fda50693-a4e2-4fb1-afcf-c6eb07647825", major: "10001", minor: "10208", lastFoundTime: 1518003454391}
3: {hash: "442e383d9c582985083b5b05f07161d2", uuid: "fda50693-a4e2-4fb1-afcf-c6eb07647825", major: "10001", minor: "10205", lastFoundTime: 1518003454392}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Here is the iBeacons array initialization:

```
iBeacons:any [] = [];
```

Comment: `*ngFor` updates everytime you update the variable. So the problem is somewhere else. Can you `console.log` the array and add the content of it to the question?

Comment: I have added some of the iBeacons array contains in my question.

Comment: Thanks, this looks ok. Instead of pushing data to the array, try to do this: `this.iBeacons = this.iBeacons.concat(newBeacon)`. I can imagine, that it wont trigger if you do not set the variable.

Comment: Still nothing displayed

Comment: Ok, how did you initialize the variable `iBeacons`, can you add this to your question aswell? And did you try to hard code some array to check if it shows up?

Comment: I have added the array initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use ChangeDetectorRef like this:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

this.event.subscribe("ibeacon", (newBeacon) => {
  this.iBeacons.push(newBeacon);
  this.cd.detectChanges();
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks that worked ;) But when I Go to previous page and start scanning again I got this Error: Uncaught Error: ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges

Comment: I figured it out. I had to unsubscribe the event. Thank you :)